# What does "der eine" mean in the follwing sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Da sah sie zwischen den Ähren fern die grauen Schloßtürme von Wartalun
>   aus den Eichen ragen, der eine trug einen Hahn, der andere das seltsam
>   verschnörkelte Doppelkreuz, das auch im Wappen des Geschlechts zu
>   finden war.

It appears to me that it means something like "one" but in another post it has been refered to as "the one."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*»der eine«* refers to *»die grauen Schlosstürme«* and means »one of the gray castle towers«.

> Schlo**ß**türme

is old [orthography](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppel-s-und-scharfes-s), not valid anymore.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Es is klar.

Comment: Why is it not valid any more?

Answer (score 1):

*The one* is a correct translation as opposed to *the other*. Of course one could shorten it to *one*, but then *another*, *the second* or also *one* would be matching counterpieces. The emphasize the counterpart aspect, I would prefer *the one*.